# MySQL Multiple Tables Link

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to these types of MySQL Queries.
Basically, I have two tables in a MySQL Database. One is called `groupmembers` and the other is called `users`

`groupmembers` contains rows with two columns, a `groupid` and a `userid`

`users` contains rows with also two columns, a `userid` and a `username`

I am trying to write a query that searches the `groupmembers` table with rows with a `groupid` of 15, but where the `userid` in `groupmembers` links with the one in `users` and searches that one too.

For example:

`SELECT * FROM groupmembers WHERE groupid = 15 (something to find the user row by using the userids) AND users.username = '%testquery%'`

If you need any more information on this, just let me know because I am bad at explaining things!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM groupmembers g INNER JOIN users u ON
g.userid = u.userid WHERE g.groupid = 15 and u.username LIKE '%testquery%'
ORDER BY u.userid
```